# how to use pg_trgm operators e.g (<-> ) in python

Tags: python-3.x, windows, postgresql, postgis, pg-trgm

I'm using the pg_trgm for similarity search on PostgreSQL DB and I need to return the results to the PostGIS table, but I'm getting this programmer error, I learned that this error is related to syntax of the sql query I tried same query in PostgreSQL and it worked, but couldn't get it to working with python. what I use (Windows 10,  Python 3.8, PostgreSQL 12.6)

```
class OSMGeocoder(object):
    """ A class to provide geocoding features using an OSM dataset in PostGIS."""
    def __init__(self, db_connectionstring):
        #db initialize db connection parameters
        self.db_connectionstring = db_connectionstring
        
    def geocode(self, placename):
        """ Geocode a given place name."""
        # here we crete the connection object
        conn = psycopg2.connect(self.db_connectionstring)
        cur = conn.cursor()
        #this is the core sql query, using triagrams to detect streets similar to a given placename
        #here we execute the sql and return all of the results
        cur.execute("SELECT name, name <-> '%s' AS weight, ST_AsText(ST_Centroid(wkb_geometry)) AS point FROM public.osm_roads ORDER BY weight LIMIT 10;" % placename)
        rows = cur.fetchall()
        conn.commit()
        cur.close()
        conn.close()
        return rows
if __name__ =='__main__':
    # the user must provide at least two parameters, the place name and the connection string to PostGIS
    if len(sys.argv) < 3 or len(sys.argv) > 3:
        print("usage: <placename> <connection string>")
        raise SystemExit
    placename = sys.argv[1]
    db_connectionstring = sys.argv[2]
    #here we instantiate the geocoder, providing the needed PostGIS connection parameters
    geocoder = OSMGeocoder(db_connectionstring)
    #here we query the geocode methiod, for getting the geocoded points for the given placenames
    results = geocoder.geocode(placename)
    print(results)
```

ProgrammingError: invalid dsn: missing "=" after "C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\runtime\kernel-ee3068bc-0b95-4bba-a373-752c8196980f.json" in connection info string

Comment: This problem has nothing to do with either pg_trgm or postgis, or with query syntax at all.  You can't connect to the database in the first place, presumably because your connection string is bad.  You haven't shown us where you got your connection string from, so what can we say about it?

Comment: Hi, first of all  thank you for your feedback. And you right it was my stupidity :D (self.db_connectionstring = 'dbname=postgis_programming user=postgres password=12345 host=localhost'_) I changed it to this now it works, I just didn't understand what was error all about it.